# Modifying the signature and defaults of a Python function, the hack-way

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the python data model better and ran into something odd.

```py
def foo(a, b = 2):
    return a / b

assert foo(20) == 10.0

# note: for sanity purposes, should also change signature, but not needed for effect
foo.__defaults__ = (10,)
assert foo(20) == 2.0

foo.__defaults__ = ()
foo.__kwdefaults__ = {'b': 10}

foo(20)  # raises TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

An error is expected: `__kwdefaults__` is for keyword-only arguments, so let's make `b` a keyword-only argument to try to solve this problem:

```py
from inspect import signature

foo.__signature__ = signature(lambda a, *, b=10: None)
foo(20)  # still raises TypeError: foo() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

**How does the error message relate to what's happening?**.

What I find strange is that neither the original function, nor my doctored one required `b` (it always had a default!). Also, `b` has never been a positional-only argument.

**What is happening here? How can one transform foo to make `b` be a keyword-only argument with default 10.**

If my original function had the signature I "injected" above, all goes well though:

```py
def foo(a, *, b=2):  # same as previous `foo`, with signature we want
    return a / b

foo.__kwdefaults__ = {'b': 10}  # change kwdefault
assert foo(20) == 2.0  # it works!!
```

Preemptive note: I know of `functools` `wraps` and `partial`, which I could use -- though in my context, I'd rather change the function itself, not a wrapped version. My question is about the behavior I created in the code above: How did it come about?

Comment: Python does not support modifying function signatures at runtime. The inspect module can use `__signature__`, but it has no affect on the function  itself; it's purely intended to aid introspection (e.g. for function wrappers). See [PEP 362](https://peps.python.org/pep-0362/).

Comment: I think my observations/questions haven't been expressed clearly enough. I edited the post to try to fix that.

Comment: @thorwhalen Your edits haven't changed anything. The function's argument default *values* are writable at runtime, but the structure of its signature is not. Arbitrary changes to the signature could invaldate the code in the body of the function, so it's not allowed. Changing parameters is okay; changing arguments is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Purpose of `__signature__`

Your issue is, that you *think* that you change a function's signature by setting `foo.__signature__`. However, this is not what's happening. It is equally useless to set it to `foo.signature` or `foo.any_other_name`. You just set a signature object to the respective property of the function, which changes nothing with regards to the function's behaviour.
The only thing that `__signature__` does is to change the behaviour of `inspect.signature()`, since it will return the signature of the function as stored in `function.__signature__` iff it is set. I.e. the only thing, that `__signature__` changes is the behaviour of `inspect.signature()`, but not the function itself.
See ekhumoro's comment for the link to the appropriate PEP.

### TypeError

As for the type error: In `foo()` `b` is not a kwarg-only argument:

```py
def foo(a, b = 2):
    return a / b
```

It is a positional argument with a default value. Hence its default value is stored in `foo.__defaults__`. When you set `foo.__defaults__ = ()` you erased those defaults. After that, `b` hence has no longer a default value and needs to be passed explicitly.

### Changing signatures

> How can one transform foo to make b be a keyword-only argument with default 10.

You cannot change a function's signature during runtime. Period.

### Changing default values

You can, however, change `b`'s default value to `10` via

```py
>>> foo.__defaults__ = (10,)
>>> foo(2)
0.2
```

Since positional arguments with default values cannot be followed by positional arguments without defaults, the tuple `__defaults__` is applied to the positional arguments from right to left.
So you can also give `a` a default value of e.g. `20` via

```py
>>> foo.__defaults__ = (20, 10)
>>> foo()
2.0
```